# Make button overlap div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button which overlaps a div. Ideally, I want the button to always appear at the bottom, center of the div even when resized. How can I go about this? Normally I can create overlapping div's when they're not needed, but when I need one, they don't work!

I have the following markup:

```css
.call_to_action{
  background-color: #000;
  height: 300px;
}
.button {
    background: #c43d3d;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    width:200px;
    text-align: center;
}
.overlap-header {
    position: relative;
}
.overlap-button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 100px auto 25px;
}
```

```html
<section class="call_to_action">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-block">
      <div class="content-block-wrapper">
        <div class="overlap-header">
          <span class="button overlap-button">Read more</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: use a negative `top`on the `.overlap-button` ?

Comment: You may give a look at flex to easily set part of the content at the bottom(even if the container is emty at the top, then use translate or negative margin to shift it outside. . https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OweRmM Not only using flex is necessary here, but also to rethink the whole structure to style only the .call_to_action as a flex container.

Answer (score 1):

You could add some negative top `margin`.

```css
.call_to_action{
  background-color: #000;
  height: 300px;
}
.button {
    background: #c43d3d;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    width:200px;
    text-align: center;
    
    top: -30px; /* <-- This */
}
.overlap-header {
    position: relative;
}
.overlap-button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 100px auto 25px;
}
```

```html
<section class="call_to_action">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-block">
      <div class="content-block-wrapper">
        <div class="overlap-header">
          <span class="button overlap-button">Read more</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: isn'it suppose to overflow at the bottom or did i misunderstood the question ?

Comment: As far as I understand, the button should always appear at the bottom

Comment: I think you're right. If that's the case, I prefer the solution which @davecar21 provided :)

Comment: Way ahead of you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this.

Make your `.call_to_action` to `display:flex;` and `position: relative;`
Then add `justify-content: center;` to make the button horizontally centered.

Then make your `.wrapper` to `position: absolute;` then add negative `bottom`.

```css
.call_to_action{
  background-color: #000;
  height: 300px;
  
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
}

.button {
    background: #c43d3d;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    width:200px;
    text-align: center;
}
.overlap-header {
    position: relative;
}
.overlap-button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="call_to_action">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-block">
      <div class="content-block-wrapper">
        <div class="overlap-header">
          <span class="button overlap-button">Read more</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```